# How to disable direct-transport for SolaceConnectionFactory using SolJMSUtility?

Tags: xml, spring, solace

I am creating `solaceConnectionFactory` using `SolJMSUtility`'s `createConnectionFactory()` method.
This is an XML configuration which looks

```
<bean id="solaceConnectionFactory" class="com.solacesystems.jms.SolJmsUtility" factory-method="createConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="props" />
</bean>

<bean id="props" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Object">
            <!-- All properties goes here -->
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The bean is created with direct-transport enabled as it is the default value.
How can I disable it with this configuration? I don't want to go to the java code and set the direct-transport using the setter method there.

Answer (score 0):

The Direct Transport property can only be set on the JNDI Connection Factory configured on the Solace PubSub+ broker itself. You can set it with SolAdmin or CLI/SEMP:

SolAdmin — Set through the Direct Transport box in the Transport Properties tab of the New JMS Connection Factory or Edit JMS Connection Factory dialog box.

CLI/SEMP — Set through Property List “transport‑properties”, Property “direct‑transport”.